# Can't get cygwin to ignore carriage return in ZSH

Tags: cygwin, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to get cygwin to ignore carriage returns so that I can get anaconda python to work. However when I add the following lines to my .zshrc file:

```sh
export SHELLOPTS
set -o igncr
```

I get the following error

```
set: no such option: igncr
```

I've also tried to put `export SHELLOPTS=igncr` in .zshrc. While this does create an envar named SHELLOPTS, but doesn't seem to have any effect on cygwin's treatment of carriage returns. All my anaconda scripts still error out because of extraneous `^M` characters at the end of lines.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I'm running windows 10 with the latest version of cygwin.

Comment: Just to be clear, treatment of carriage returns *by your shell* is a feature of your shell, not Cygwin itself.  What you tried does work in bash.  I don't know if it works in zsh.

Comment: Good point. I changed the title to specify that it is zsh specific.

Answer (score 0):

as of June 9, 2020 and **May 15, 2022**... it is not possible!.
check out [@mcornella](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9017#issuecomment-641519682)'s reply to the very same question.
the best one can do is *"to edit files in LF mode instead"*.
(don't know exactly what *files* to edit though)